# Are all $30n + 7$ numbers prime numbers where $n$ is a whole number?

Tags: prime-numbers

So I was lying on my bed and I began to wonder about prime numbers and as I went through each prime number I found that numbers $37, 67, 97, 127, 157, \ldots$ all happen to be prime numbers (correct me if I am wrong). Is there a way to mathematically prove this?

Comment: what if $n=7$? :)

Comment: How about $7777$?

Comment: What if $n$ is a multiple of $7$.   $210+7 = 7(30+1)$.  $420 = 7(61)$.  And $30(7k) + 7 = 7(30k + 1)$.

Comment: For a non-trivial example.  $30*8 + 7 = 247 = 13*19$

Comment: Find a sequence where the first 5  terms are prime is not really that significant.  As this is constructed so it cant be divisible by $2,3,5$ the next primes are "kind of" large so we should expect it to take around 7 to 11 terms to find a non-prime.

Comment: You only had to check one more case!  $187 = 11 \cdot 17$

Comment: On the positive side, there are [infinitely many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) primes of this kind... sorry for an off-topic :[|||]:

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate. But I can't find the original...

Comment: try harder! [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/prime_numbers.html) is a list of all primes <=1000

Comment: If $30n+7$ was always prime, then the prime numbers would not be too much of a mystery as it is today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Choose $n=7$ for example, and the number is divisible by $7$.

Comment: @ThePhenotype I wrote my answer at the same time as the comment :). As soon as I have submitted it, I saw the comment.

Comment: It's an answer.  That the comment is also an answer doesn't matter.  This *is* an answer.

Comment: @fleablood Alrighty. Both of you please forgive my cynicism.

Answer (score 2):

If $7|n$ then $30(7k) + 7 = 7(30k + 1)$ so,.... no.

But also.  If $p$ is relatively prime to $7,2,3,5$ then there an $k$ so that $30*k\equiv 1 \mod p$. And so if $n\equiv -7k\mod p$ then $30n + 7 \equiv 0 \mod p$ and so $p|30n + 7$.

Example.  if $p = 13$ then $30\equiv 4\mod 13$ and $4*10\equiv 40 \equiv 1 \mod 13$.

$-7\equiv 6\mod 13$ so if $n\equiv 10*6 = 60\equiv 8\mod 13$ then $30*8 + 7 = 247 = 13*19$.

Answer (score 2):

So you stopped right short of the first counterexample: $30 \times 6 + 7 = 187 = 11 \times 17$. On Wolfram Alpha (if you don't have Wolfram Mathematica) type `Select[Range[100], Not[PrimeQ[30# + 7]] &]` and press Enter for more examples of $n$.

Obviously $30n + 7$ will be composite if $n$ is itself a multiple of 7, like the faster answerers already said. So for example $30 \times 7 + 7 = 217 = 7 \times 31$.

And for what it's worth, negative $n$ will also give you composite numbers, like for example $-5 \times 30 + 7 = -143 = -1 \times 11 \times 13$.

Answer (score 2):

We can actually be quite precise about how often a number of the form $30n+7$ is prime, thanks to the Prime Number Theorem for Arithmetic Progressions.  In this case it shows that for large values of $x$, the number of positive integers $n \le x$ such that $30n+7$ is prime is approximately (asymptotically equal to)
$$\frac{15}{4} \frac{x}{\log x}.$$

Since that quantity goes to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, there are indeed infinitely many prime values of $30n+7$ (a fact that also follows from the slightly weaker Dirichlet’s theorem).  But since that same quantity is eventually smaller than $x$, $30n+7$ is not *always* — nor is it even usually — prime.  The fact that the approximate count doesn’t drop below $x$ until $x>42$ or so is a partial explanation for why the frequency of primes is so high for the first few values of $n$ that you believed the pattern might continue.